# Difficulty installing Google Tag Manager in React for Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to install Google Tag Manager on my React site, but when I read the documentation for Google Tag Manager it indicates that I should paste a long script tag into the head and body of every page:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

However, React sites do not traditionally use the script tag. How can I effectively and efficiently set my React site up with Google Tag Manager? Are there special React or JavaScript tags for SPAs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add that script in /public/index.html since its a single page app but will only load once unless you add events depending on what your Google Tags do.

To implement Google Tag Manager, use NPM package for more customizable options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-tag-manager

If you're using Google analytics within your tag manger, read below.

Best approach is to use Google Analytics React NPM Package: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga

Add: `ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);` in your router change to make sure you get your page hits.

Comment: I thought the purpose of Google Tag Manager was to avoid using Google Analytics events. You're saying it's best to combine them?

Comment: If youre using Google Tag Manager just for Google Analytics, I would go the GA NPM package. Since React (event with routes), is only a one page app (index.html), you would need to add manual events as pageviews as your url changes or youre hitting your components as a 'page'.

Check docs: 
`import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);` . You are letting React take care of analytics for you instead of embedding just HTML into your /public/index.html which will only record initial page visits.

Comment: When does Google Tag Manager become useful?

Comment: I never found it useful. Perhaps someone else may chime in and provide their use cases. Google Tag Manager may become effective when you want a program area (in a different division without technical expertise) to control a portion of your web implementation to perform an action without involving IT. If you setup a website correctly, you would have a constant header file where you can add a script that will take affect on each page, such as a Google Analytics script.  Since React is a beast on its own, I dont think you would get much use out of Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Some implementations of GA using GTM with React/single page app: https://medium.com/@j3y/analytics-with-react-redux-spas-and-google-tag-manager-4d3a55833619 
https://www.pmg.com/blog/tracking-single-page-web-apps-google-tag-manager-analytics/

Comment: I found this article useful as binding tag manager in react project: https://medium.com/finnovate-io/integrating-google-tag-manager-with-a-react-app-5a8584ee2251

Comment: Once follow up the site react has been add tag manager: https://vacha-design.com/